# Bison - 2 shift/reduce conflicts

Tags: compiler-construction, conflict, bison, yacc

I've been staring at my code for a while now and I have no idea how I resolve this issue. I have used the debugger to locate the issue but I don't understand the error.

```
number_constant :   integer
                |   SUBTRACT integer
                |   SUBTRACT integer PERIOD integer
                |   integer PERIOD integer
                ;
digit           :   INTEGER
                ;
integer         :   digit
                |   integer digit
                ;
```

These are the 2 states the output tells me the conflicts are

```
state 38

36 number_constant: integer .
40 decimal_constant: integer . PERIOD integer
46 integer: integer . digit

INTEGER  shift, and go to state 6
PERIOD   shift, and go to state 55

PERIOD    [reduce using rule 36 (number_constant)]
$default  reduce using rule 36 (number_constant)

digit  go to state 56    

------------------

state 46

37 number_constant: SUBTRACT integer .
39 decimal_constant: SUBTRACT integer . PERIOD integer
46 integer: integer . digit

INTEGER  shift, and go to state 6
PERIOD   shift, and go to state 65

PERIOD    [reduce using rule 37 (number_constant)]
$default  reduce using rule 37 (number_constant)

digit  go to state 56
```

entire output: http://pastebin.com/bUxYZeHr

Thanks in advance

Comment: `PERIOD` can be shifted or reduced, bison doesn't know which one to choose, read about LR parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar includes

```
27 term: value
28     | value PERIOD term
29     | value DIVIDE term
```

A `value` can be an `integer` and a `term` can be a `value`, so `integer PERIOD integer` could be a `decimal_constant` or a `term`.

The only possible resolution is to remove the ambiguity. What is `23.4` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are doing my Compiler coursework. Seems better to me to come to the class/labs and ask me for help rather than asking on stackoverflow when you can get it direct much quicker!

The actual problem, which I am sure you have found by now; as your assignment has been handed in, is that some of the work is done in the lexer in flex and some in the parser in bison. The token INTEGER from flex contains all the digits and there should not be a rule in bison for a sequence of digits.